# Appcelerator Studio 4 crashes on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I got invited to Appcelerator Studio 4, and when i try to launch Appcelerator Studio from Ubuntu 15.04, i get this error:

```
simion@simion-U31SG:~$ ./opt/Appcelerator_Studio/AppceleratorStudio 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
sudo: a password is required
Exception in thread "Installing dependencies" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$6.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:407)
```

It remains stuck like this forever.
[image: crash]

Comment: Have the same problem. Any luck with this?

Comment: Still not working ...

Comment: Facing similar issue on ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 64bit. This is really frustrating that the community ppl is not coming forward to fix this issue.